# UpdatePanel does full postback first time

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, postback

I have a custom control that has an update panel in it. Within the update panel, there are no custom controls, but there are custom controls outside the update panel. All controls have an ID set as do the parents of the controls. Inside the update panel is a repeater that has controls that should trigger an async postback. The update panel has an update mode of conditional and children as triggers is off. The update panel renders standalone divs, not table cells. EnablePartialRendering is on on the script manager.

Each repeater item has numerous textboxes, but two of them have autopostback turned on. Inside the repeater ItemDataBound event, I register the control with the script manager's RegisterAsyncPostBackControl.

If I edit either textbox, it does a callback correctly. But after the first one is edited, if you edit the other one, it does a full postback. It doesn't matter which one is done first. But after it's done its postback, if you edit either of the textboxes, it does callbacks correctly.

I've tried several things like changing the UpdateMode and ChildrenAsTriggers properties to various combinations. Nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of things can cause this, compare [UpdatePanel causes full page postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241201/updatepanel-causes-full-page-postback) with [LinkButton in ListView in UpdatePanel causes full postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652728/linkbutton-in-listview-in-updatepanel-causes-full-postback).

You'll need to provide more information, e.g. .NET Framework version, IIS version etc. exact ASP.NET markup etc

But since you asked for "*Any suggestions?*" try looking through [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=updatepanel%20full%20postback)

Comment: I read through most of those already, but there was a comment about changing the ClientIdMode to AutoId which seems to have done the trick. Thanks for the kick.

Comment: @Eric glad you found your answer maybe someone will create an exhaustive list of all the potential reasons for a Full Postback...