# MS Ajax Update Panel does not function after adding DevExpress components to project

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, devexpress

After installing and adding DevExpress 15.2 components to my Visual Studio 2015, whatever I do I can't work with ms ajax update panel.

AsyncPostPack is never happening and Timer does not work anymore. triggers either within update panel or outside don't work anymore.

If I create a new project everything is fine but as soon as I add a single dx component to my page, I'm not able to work with ajax toolkit anymore

this is my page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ajax.aspx.cs" Inherits="bimehPortal.ajax" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is code-behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateLabels();
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateLabels();
    }
    private void UpdateLabels()
    {
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

this is what i have as output. as you can see after clicking the button page is reloading...

[image]

this is my web.config file just in case you need:

```
 <!--
 For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
-->
 <configuration>
 <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="devExpress">
        <section name="themes" type="DevExpress.Web.ThemesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v15.2, Version=15.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
        <section name="compression" type="DevExpress.Web.CompressionConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v15.2, Version=15.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
        <section name="settings" type="DevExpress.Web.SettingsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v15.2, Version=15.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
        <section name="errors" type="DevExpress.Web.ErrorsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v15.2, Version=15.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
        <system.Web>
            <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
        </system.Web>
-->
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v15.2, Version=15.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v15.2, Version=15.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.Printing.v15.2.Core, Version=15.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.RichEdit.v15.2.Core, Version=15.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v15.2, Version=15.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"/>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxPivotGrid.v15.2, Version=15.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
            <add assembly="DevExpress.PivotGrid.v15.2.Core, Version=15.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/></assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        </namespaces>
        <controls>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
        </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
        <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v15.2, Version=15.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v15.2, Version=15.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET" path="DX.ashx" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
        <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v15.2, Version=15.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
        <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v15.2, Version=15.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET" path="DX.ashx" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<devExpress>
    <themes enableThemesAssembly="true" styleSheetTheme="" theme="" customThemeAssemblies=""/>
    <compression enableHtmlCompression="false" enableCallbackCompression="true" enableResourceCompression="true" enableResourceMerging="true"/>
    <settings doctypeMode="Html5" rightToLeft="false" embedRequiredClientLibraries="false" ieCompatibilityVersion="edge"/>
    <errors callbackErrorRedirectUrl=""/>
</devExpress>
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: place button outside Update panel and then do aysnctrigger button id

Comment: ok. i will tell you.

Comment: should i put label inside update panel?

Comment: no. I put button outside updatepanel and then do as you said but it is refreshing page again.

Comment: I checked in both case it's working at my end. Can you place your Scriptmanagar in MasterPage Instead of in your current page and check

Comment: Is there any configuration settings in web.config or any thing else? i just read the Microsoft's blog and followed their instructions to do what i want but the page is always refreshing.

Comment: roger that. wait...

Comment: Is there anything in your page,that is refreshing the page at regular interval in meta tag check in master page.

Comment: i just put script manager inside master but it is again no use.

Comment: i tried it within a page without master page but it is the same again. looks like something is wrong, i mean maybe a configuration in somewhere.

Comment: There is no problem in code its fine.

Comment: im updating question, please take a look

Comment: to check both cases. none of them work.

Comment: @Ali.Rashidi, I tried your code and it's working fine, both buttons only produce a partial postback. Analyzing the network with the developer tool shows that the responses only contain the UpdatePanel. Does this page as-is produce a full page postback in your local? Have you tried with a new webforms project just in case there's some configuration causing the problem?

Comment: I tried your code, it's really working very perfect

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Like some others already mentioned the code is working just fine. What is happening inside `Button1_Click` and `Button2_Click`? Maybe the problem is in there... Post that and we can help you further. If for example there is a `Response.Write` in there it will not work.

Comment: "i want to change the text of label on button click without refreshing my page."
You can not accomplish this using just an Update Panel. both you buttons will automatically cause a postback and refresh only the update panel. 
If what you are asking is for no postback(?), then you must use front-end code such as Javascript

Comment: thank you all for your comment. i agree that this code should work fine but not in my case. when i click on buttons, it should change the contents of label without refreshing the page. just like when you add a comment here. right? but when i click on button a "loading circle" appears in firefox tab. i mean it is not what it should be

Comment: @Andrew that behavior you said is expected but there is something wrong here. i tried to create new projects but nothing changed

Comment: `Button2_Click` will always do postback since is outside of `panel`... but `Button1` will do partial postback (let's say, refresh only `updatepanel`)... try to change to this `<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">`... btw. postback will triggered always, I think, but only changes into `updatepanel` will be affected.

Comment: i used to do so but nothing changes

Comment: Did you try with another browser? How do you tell it's a full postback?

Comment: because i have two controls, one within update panel another outside. when i click on button 1 only contents of one label should change but they change both. and yes i did try it on IE, firefox, Chrome

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion 1**

Your code should work fine. It is normal for a button click to trigger a postback (as the name `AsyncPostBackTrigger` indicates). However, only the content of the UpdatePanel should be refreshed.

A good way to test it is to add a Label outside of the UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label" />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button2_Click"/>
```

In code-behind, you can update both Labels when either button is clicked:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateLabels();
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateLabels();
}

private void UpdateLabels()
{
    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

If the partial update works correctly, you should see that `Label1` is updated when a button is clicked, while `Label2` is not.

---

**Suggestion 2**

Since the configuration setting `<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy"/>` can cause the kind of behavior that you see in your application (as reported in [UpdatePanel causes full page postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241201/updatepanel-causes-full-page-postback)), you can eliminate that potential problem with the following setting in your `Web.config` file:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <xhtmlConformance mode="Transitional"/>
</system.web>
```

---

**Suggestion 3**

In some situations where no DevExpress component is visible in the page, the following code must be executed to make sure that the client scripts are registered (see [this discussion](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T264235) on DevExpress technical support forum):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ASPxWebControl.RegisterBaseScript(this);
}
```

Comment: i did as exactly you said. and uploaded a photo as a result. there is a postback but a full post back.

Comment: contents of both labels change. is there something wrong in configuration file or maybe vs2015 or anything else?

Comment: I added a suggestion for the `xhtmlconformance` setting in Web.config.

Comment: i really hate such problems. thank you but did not solved the problem. can be there something wrong about "Ajax client framework" ?

Comment: At this point, I don't know what causes your problem. I would like to test your configuration but there are several references to DevExpress components, which I don't have. Can you make a new project without any reference to these components?

Comment: yes! it is working now. but i need that project to use ajax not this one. what causes the problem?

Comment: That gives you a way to debug the problem. You can gradually introduce the DevExpress components in the Web.config of the new project, until you find the problematic setting/component. Once you find it, we can see if there is something to do about it.

Comment: I added a 3rd suggestion. You can give it a try.

Comment: i started to learn about DevExpress CallbackPanel. that is much easier and better. it seems DX disables ajax for some configuration reasons. if i give this bounty to no one after tomorrow, will it be mine again or do I have to give it to someone?

Comment: anyway I think you deserve this 50 :)

Comment: Thanks. I had seen discussions about the CallbackPanel but I thought there was a way to use the UpdatePanel with DevExpress (trying to answer your question). Just curious: did you try `RegisterBaseScript` with the UpdatePanel?

Comment: no actually. sometimes ignoring problems is better than to solve them . never mind.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your browser supports partial rendering (which it likely does), and that `EnablePartialRendering` is `true`. The default is `true` which is probably why it works for others, but there are also some underlying requirements for ScriptManager that may not be met on your system, causing it to be `false`. See [EnablePartialRendering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.enablepartialrendering.aspx) and [SupportsPartialRendering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.supportspartialrendering.aspx)  for example.

You may also want to review the [UpdatePanel Control Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx) on MSDN for more detail on the requirements and gotchas of using this control.

Comment: i saw that msdn blog. i followed their instruction but no use. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to add "UseSubmitBehavior="false""

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

<asp:Button ID="Button2" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button2_Click"/>
```